# Accessing camera at same time

Tags: android, android-camera

Let say there is an online proctor application that is using webcam while examination and they're giving

an option to upload the photo of written answer that is on A4 sheet through camera.

So i just want to know is it possible that when we're taking picture of answer at that time also they using camera as a webcam .

because i think it can use either for webcam or for clicking photos

Comment: This contains all the information you need: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html